# Folder disappear from NAS only in Finder

Tags: macos, terminal, finder, nas

I'm using a Lenovo ix4-300d has my backup system for my archives and it work pretty well. The only downside right now (and it's not even them fault) is that some folder has disappeared from my Finder view. I still can access them via Terminal (not SSH, just cd into Volumes/share-name/archives) or via the web interface of the ix4-300d. Do someone have an idea how I can get them back on my Finder listing? I've already tried to delete .DS_Store via the web interface and I got no luck.

Here is a screenshot from my 3 views…

[image: Terminal / Finder / Web Interface]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the OSX system (i.e., Finder) is treating the folder *like* a hidden folder? In which case, it would be useful for you to have an Automator script that toggles the Hidden flag in the Finder. Once the script is created, it appears as a menu item under **Finder** menu >> **Services**.

Here is the link to a previous discussion concerning [showing hidden files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20469894/how-to-make-a-script-to-show-hide-hidden-files-in-mac-os-x).